# If I were to "cheat" a card into play, would Kurgadon activate?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I had a [Kurgadon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=45165) and a [Didgeridoo](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=201317), hacked to say "beast" instead of "minotaur" with [Artificial Evolution](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=39923), in play, and I used Didgeridoo to put [Symbiotic Beast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=39924) into play, would Kurgadon's ability trigger?

I am thinking no, since I am not **casting** the Symbiotic Beast, just putting it into play.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading the gatherer wording for older cards can make the analysis easier.

[Didgeridoo](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=201317):

> {3}: You may put a Minotaur permanent card from your hand onto the battlefield.

[Kurgadon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=45165)

> Whenever you cast a creature spell with converted mana cost 6 or greater, put three +1/+1 counters on Kurgadon.

So you are correct, clearly the Didgeridoo does not cast a creature spell, so the Kurgadon's ability will not trigger.

Comment: Well this is good information. Thanks! Unfortunately I was hoping to be wrong.. But oh well! Saves me some embarrassment later.

Comment: @MiloGertjejansen Cards like [Garruk's Packleader](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253687) or [Gruul Ragebeast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366398) will work with sneak-into-play effects.

Comment: @AlexP Hmm.. That would be worth looking at. I have a few Gruul Ragebeast's around. I also looked at [Adaptive Snapjaw](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366290) to evolve the crap out of it.

Comment: I don't know if you can say "clearly" - Digerdoo's card text states "as though it had just been summoned" - when you consider the vast number of rules around summoning, this text is hardly clear in any stretch of the imagination. It might be an easy decision for those familiar with the rules, but it is not immediately clear, given the text on the card, that it you do not *treat the creature the same* as having been cast.

Comment: @corsiKa Digerdoo's card text **used to say** "as though it has just been summoned" which is why I said *reading the gatherer wording for older cards can make the analysis easier.* This is why Wizards has a canonical source for card rules text: to keep interpretations current with modern rules and templates.

Comment: @corsiKa In other words, my usage of the word *clearly* is clearly in the context of my answer: referring to the modern functionality of the card, and was not referring to what's printed on the card. Gatherer ("Oracle Wording") is what's used in rules interpretations in MtG tournaments.

Answer (score 4):

***Casting* refers only to putting spells on the stack, not moving cards from one zone to another by other means.**

> 601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pays its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect.

In this case, you're putting an ability activation on the stack, but the card in question goes directly from your hand to the battlefield, so nothing is cast.

(Note also that casting refers to moving the object *onto* the stack — objects created on the stack, like storm copies, also aren't "cast".)